# 3d engine for iPhone

Tags: iphone, 3d-engine

Which engine is best ?

I've finded some engines : **Ogre**, **Irrlicht** and **direct rendering** from opengles (convert .obj files into buffer and rendering it).

I've compiled Ogre - CeGUI works very ugly on iPhone... And Ogre has many-many files :)

I need just rotate, zoom and object picking for static objects.
Which method/engine is better ?

And, for example, when i use Ogre - can I use antialiasing ?
When I have rendering directly by glDrawArrays, i can use software AA (for example, jitter method).
Can this some of engines?

Comment: You cannot ask "Which is the best", there's no "Answer" for this question, it's not a question, it's a debate... this is a question answering website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at http://isgl3d.com/. It is written in Objective-C, simple, compact and is appropriate for your needs.

There is also Cocos3d (an extension to cocos2d which can handles simple 3d things) with no physics and collision detection but I prefer isgl3d.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to render some static objects with rotation and zoom, you can write it from scratch in OpenGL ES in much less time than what is needed to learn to use a big 3D engine like Ogre or Irrlicht.

Comment: And what about AA for iPhone in Ogre or Irrlicht ?

Answer (score 1):

http://nineveh.gl/ - NinevehGL not yet released but it's really easy to learn engine

Answer (score 0):

I've used Irrlicht for years and I love it. Very easy to learn, very fast and a breeze to compile and use.

Comment: I like Irrlicht too. Is there a prebuilt version of Irrlicht (or instructions to build it) for iOS?